# phonegap cloud build app (apk) Not working for Android and Iphone

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an app on local machine Android everything is working fine. Maps / Image Sliders/ Price Sliders / Splash Screens. I have tested entire app to be working fine on simulator and real android device. 
**But When I upload the zip Soln & Run Cloud build and Install cloud build nothing seems to be working.**

- Splash Not coming.  Only landing page is showing.  I can not navigate
  to other pages Server requests are not working.
- Application is purly html based no intents or plugins are used in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually issue was in Adobe cloud. We worked with same build the day after and it started working. But still the splash screen is not working.
We plan to have 2 Builds for android and iOS. Android build we will do on our server by installing SDK. IOS build we will be doing on cloud.
Since cloud build apk Size is >6mb while Local Build apk is <2mb